# How to add custom managed metadata on Yammer group

Tags: sorting, sharepoint-2013, metadata, yammer

We use Yammer at my place of work, and we are looking for a way of sorting groups in custom manners. To that end, it'd helpful if we could add custom metadata to all the groups that currently exist. Is there any well-defined manner of doing so or, if not, are there ways of achieving custom sorting (*i.e.*, according to our own defined criteria) of groups in Yammer? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the product, and it's unlikely to be something added at a platform level. You may be better to raise this over on the [Yammer UserVoice](https://yammer.uservoice.com/) site. It would also be useful to drill down a bit into "why" this is useful to you when you post there. I can think of why I might want this, but it may not be the same need as you.